# Hide HTML with PHP conditional - Not working

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to get a piece of PHP code to run inside of my HTML file.

I have a drop down menu.  If users select one item, it should display additional fields.  So, I want them to only display if they select that item from the drop down menu.  I am trying to select it based on the value for that drop down item. I have not declared any PHP values in a PHP script.  This is all in HTML.

I know that with jquery you have to pull in the jquery library before running the script.  Do I need to do this with PHP also?

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
  if ($dropmenuValue == "specificParameter") {
?>
  <div>
    -conditional content-
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of the quotes around `"true"` if it really is a boolean value

Comment: You can't run `php` in an `html` page. By default, a server will present a page with an `.html` extention as is. You can, of course have `html` in a `php` page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  if ($value ) {
  ?>
 <div>
-conditional content-
 </div>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the $values variable like this

```
$value = true
```

Then you can do

```
<? if($value){ ?>
   <div>Content Here</div>
<? } ?>
```

Is the page a .php page?

Comment: No, the page is HTML.

I am using the data gathered to send out in a form.  But, I don't want those fields to show unless they select one of two possible choices.  

Do I need to call in any PHP APIs or anything to get PHP to work in my HTML page?

Where do I declare "$value = true" when doing inline PHP?

Comment: If the .html page is not included within a .php page then the php code will not run.  I.E. <?php include("file.html"); ?>Then the code will run.

Answer (score 1):

A multi conditional statement is done in a different manner. The manner being:

```
<?php if($val): ?>
     <div>
       -conditional content-
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your comparing a boolean to a String.That's why your code won't work I would suggest something like `If($value){` or `if($value==true){`.

Answer (score 0):

you want to do if($value == true). The quotes you have around true does not make it a boolean variable.
Everything else in your code looks find.

tldr: correct: if($value == true) ----------
incorrect: if($value == "true")

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($value ):?>
  <div>
    -conditional content-
  </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Here are a few pointers.

$value is a boolean value. It is best to evaluate using if($value)

The PHP if syntax used above is a much cleaner way.

You will be able to see where your if statement begins and ends.

Enjoy!